# Как посчитать сколько раз прерывалась серия чисел?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно получить число сколько раз прерывалась серия чисел. На пример серия 1,4,6,9,10 прервалась 3 раза. Пробовал что то в этом направлении, но не получается додумать...

```
var mynumbers = new Array(1,4,6,9,10);
var maxnumber = Math.max(...mynumbers);

var missing_count = 0;

for(var i=1;i<=maxnumber;i++)
{
   if(mynumbers[i-1] != i){
     missing_count++;
   }
}

console.log(missing_count);
```

Comment: 1 - все числа идут по возрастанию?
2 - прерывание, это когда следующее число больше предыдущего, больше чем на один?

Comment: 1. да, всегда будут по возрастанию. 2. больше, но не обязательно на 1

Comment: `if ((mynumbers[i] - mynumbers[i-1]) > 1)...`

Comment: `let c=i=0; for (;i<arr.length-1;) c+=arr[i++]+1<arr[i];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать например таким способом:

```js
var arr = [1,4,6,9,10];

var count = arr.reduce(function (res, current, index) {
  if (arr[index + 1] - current > 1) res += 1;
  return res;
}, 0);

console.log(count)
```

Либо с другим синтаксисом:

```js
const arr = [1,4,6,9,10];
const count = arr.reduce((res, current, index) => (arr[index + 1] - current > 1) ? res + 1 : res, 0);
console.log(count)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!!!!